# Parallel.ForEach vs foreach for I/O bound Tasks

Tags: c#, multithreading, foreach, parallel.foreach

I read most of the times I should not use multithreading like `Parallel.ForEach`for I/O bound tasks.
I did some tests with a simple XPath search over 15.000 xml documents. The tested `XPath` is a simple `'//element'` which is found in 1333 of the 15.000 files.

I did a simple foreach:

```
foreach (var file in files)
{
    XPathDocument xDoc = null;
    using (XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(file, xrSettings))
        xDoc = new XPathDocument(xr);
    XPathNavigator xNav = xDoc.CreateNavigator();
    xNav = xNav.SelectSingleNode(xpath);
    if (xNav != null)
        results.Add(Path.GetFileName(file));
}
```

and a simple `Parallel.ForEach`:

```
Parallel.ForEach(files, file =>
{
    XPathDocument xDoc = null;
    using (XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(file, xrSettings))
        xDoc = new XPathDocument(xr);
     XPathNavigator xNav = xDoc.CreateNavigator();
     xNav = xNav.SelectSingleNode(xpath);
     if (xNav != null)
         results.Add(Path.GetFileName(file));
});
```

I have tested both versions 3 times with the same data to consider the filesystem cache:

> foreach: 39,6 seconds
>
> Parallel.ForEach: 7,34 seconds

Why should I use foreach for this task, when `Parallel.ForEach` is so much faster? Or is this just CPU bound and the reading of the xml files from disk

Comment: `Or is this just CPU bound` Yes, basically. You are not only loading the XML from the disk, but you are parsing it and then traversing it - which will be done in memory.

Comment: "I read most of the times I should not use multithreading like `Parallel.ForEach` for I/O bound tasks". Where did you read that?

Comment: @Tdorno Regardless of where they read it, it's correct in 99.99% of cases. There's no reason to spin up multiple threads when they get bottlenecked reading from the same disk. Unless you have one thread per physical disk, that is.

Comment: @Rob I did not consider the parsing of the xml. So pure I/O work would be something like `File.Copy`, `File.Exist` or downloading a file with HttpClient?

Comment: @Tony Yes, essentially. Or simply reading the file into memory, and then processing it in parallel. However, the way you're doing it now is fine, there isn't really a pressing reason to avoid parallelism if you're doing the read/process in parallel, not to mention it would be a lot messier. I would be hesitant to benchmark downloading a file, as that can be affected by many external factors, but yes, in many cases, downloading in parallel is more performant than sequentially.

Comment: @Rob Maybe you should post what you said as an answer?